# Subscribe to std::cout stream (stdout) on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, stdout, cout

In my app, I log everything and send it to the cloud via a custom logger.

I also use some C++ libraries that make use of `cout`.

I would like to tap into `cout` stream and send it to the cloud without making changes to the C++ libraries.

I tried to use `FileHandle.standardOutput` and send the text to a `UITextView` (as a test) but the `readabilityHandler` doesn't get called:

```
let fileHandler = FileHandle.standardOutput    
fileHandler.readabilityHandler = { fileHandler in
    let newText = String(data: fileHandler.availableData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "NO-Text"
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.logTextView.text.append(newText)
        self.fileHandler.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
    }
}
fileHandler.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
```

Did someone try to do something similar? Knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have C++ code under your control that you're writing as part of your app (as distinct from the C++ code in the libraries you're using) it is possible to redirect `cout` by changing its stream buffer before using any functions in the libraries - for example see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/ for a technique.    If you don't have such C++ code, then this question is off-topic as C++   (you'll be looking for a solution in another language).

Comment: Well that's an option - but in this technique, I will redirect stdout - I just want to listen to it.

Comment: In that case, your question of off-topic as C++, since "listening" is not supported in standard C++.

Comment: OK thanks - I removed the C++ tag